# Run second sub after first sub, without calling it from first sub

Tags: vb.net

I have a situation where I've got an event handler handling an unselect event.
That event has no cancel or before or after settings, but I want to cancel the unselection or reselect afterwards.
I thought to just add a select command at the end of the unselect event sub to reselect it, but the actual unselect is performed after the sub finishes, so my new select will still be undone.

Is there a way to let a sub follow up another sub, without actually calling it?
Then I can do a new select after the event sub finishes.

The question is a general question, but the situation occurs in an Autodesk Inventor Add-In:

```
Private WithEvents _eInteractEvents As InteractionEvents
Private WithEvents _eSelectEvents As SelectEvents

Private Sub _eSelectEvents_OnUnSelect(UnSelectedEntities As ObjectsEnumerator, SelectionDevice As SelectionDeviceEnum, ModelPosition As Point, ViewPosition As Point2d, View As View) Handles _eSelectEvents.OnUnSelect

    'This is where I want to cancel the unselecting or reselect the original selection.
    'The ObjectsEnumerator can't be manipulated.

End Sub ' Only at this point the unselecting is actually performed, so any previous made selections are still unselected.
```

Comment: Please add your current code here for us to inspect. Also if you already know when catching the event that you want to cancel the "unselecting" then set the selection again to the control you are unselecting.

Comment: I've added some more details about the situation.

Comment: Use `BeginInvoke()` to call the method that performs the selection after the current event handler has completed its task

Comment: Are you saying that while `_eSelectEvents_OnUnSelect` is running you want to undo its effect, or that you want it to have no effect when it is called? If the latter, you could either remove the event handler or set a flag that the event handler checks before running its body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your responses.
It's not possible to remove the event handler, since only in certain situations the event should be canceled/undone.

Jimi's response with BeginInvoke did the job for me.